# Best Practices WCF Service - Windows Azure

Tags: wcf, azure

How can i save some metadata from a windows forms application to an SQL Azure Database by using an Azure WCF service?

If I have 100 clients that will access the WCF service at the same time or different time saving this metadata to the database ... what is the best way of implementing this?

The client will pass to the WCF service the metadata serialized (XML or JSON), web service will deserialize it and save it to the SQL Server db. The message sent my the client will send an unique ID to the service and before the service enters the metadata to the SQL db whill check if that uniqe ID exists or not.

Any help with this will be highly appreciated!

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds to me like you answered your question when you asked it!  Your solution here would look almost identical to what you'd do on premises.

Create a `WCF Service Web Role` and implement your service as you would when running on premises, and deploy that to `Windows Azure`.  Within your service method, use `ADO.NET/Entity Framework/Linq-to-SQL` to write to the `SQL Azure database` just as you would to a on-premises SQL Server.  In your Windows Forms application create a service proxy to the Azure hosted service and invoke the WCF method passing in your serialized metadata.

Is there a particular part of the architecture you're stuck on?

Comment: Hi and thanks for your answer. I am stuck in the security part of this implementation and the serialization/deserialization of the message and send it to the service. Do you have any samples or can you advise how to proceed implementing this? P.S.The service will not return anything to the client